# Transferring received Serial Port Data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serial-port

I am using LiveCharts and Serial port data to draw a Line Graph. I've got the data coming in from another class, meanwhile the graph functions is in its own separate class. I am trying to get the data coming off of the serial port to equal my X axis. Here is my code:

Graph Code:

```
    public ChartValues<ChartDataPoints> Values { get; set; }

    public GraphControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //Mapper
        var mapper = Mappers.Xy<ChartDataPoints>()
            .X(model => model.Session)
            .Y(model => model.Value);

        Charting.For<ChartDataPoints>(mapper);
        Values = new ChartValues<ChartDataPoints>();
        var _session = new Stopwatch();
        _session.Start();

        //Task
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30);

                //we add the lecture based on our StopWatch instance
                Values.Add(new ChartDataPoints
                {
                    Session = _session.ElapsedMilliseconds,
                    Value = 1 //This needs to be replaced with data from the Serial port!!
                });
            }
        });

        DataContext = this;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

}
```

ChartDataPoints Class:

```
public class ChartDataPoints
{
    public double Session { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my SerialPort class: (It is in a seperate project called Hardware.)

```
    public ForceCellData()
    {
        try
        {
            string _port3 = "COM3";
            SerialPort defaultSerial = new SerialPort(_port3);
            defaultSerial.BaudRate = 9600;
            defaultSerial.Parity = Parity.None;
            defaultSerial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            defaultSerial.DataBits = 8;
            defaultSerial.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            defaultSerial.RtsEnable = true;
            defaultSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            defaultSerial.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to COM3!");
        }
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

        indata = indata.Trim().Replace("\r", string.Empty);
        indata = indata.Trim().Replace("\n", string.Empty);
        indata = indata.Trim().Replace("-", string.Empty);
        var split = indata.Split('.');


        foreach (var stringData in split)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringData) && double.TryParse(stringData, out double convertdata))
            {
                double Xdata;
                Xdata = convertdata; //Don't know what to do here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what am I missing to be able to get data coming from the serial port to equal the variable Value? So that the graph will draw the data coming from the Serial port?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate projects then you need some form of a connection between them, also reference SerialPort class in the graph code somewhere or else how do you expect to access indata.

Otherwise if you don't want active plotting then save the data from ForceCellData in a txt file and then read from it and plot it using the graph code at a later time.